# Why do my Unity3D sprites look pixelated when rendered on my iPhone?

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine, pixel

I'm a newbie in Unity3D, I'm making a 2D game, but, I'm making the menu, and it's all pixelated! Om my PC it looks fine, but when I run it on my iPhone, it pixelates.

I have the "compress assets on import" option turned off, and the image's original size is bigger than the size that have in Unity!

This is how it looks on my iPhone:

[image: a very pixelated logo and image rendering - no antialiasing on most edges]

And this is how it looks on my PC:

[image: as above, but smooth]

PS: All of the components are buttons with PNG images; I don't know if that affects anything.

Comment: What are you doing with your canvas scaler?  (It should be located on your canvas object in your scene.)  Typically if I am aiming for a set resolution I set my canvas scaler to scale with screen size, and depending on my resolution settings (Portrait or landscape) I change my scale ratio based off of that, from there you can get a better idea how your project will look on a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sprite import settings, change "Filter Mode" to "Point".

[image: Example]

I believe this prevents the blurring on small screens as displayed items are enlarged and let things stay sharp (pixelated).

Comment: Also you can change the compression to High Quality.

Comment: Where is Sprite Import Settings Located?

Comment: Click on your sprite file in the project panel

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can try is to set your font-size up high, then scale your objects up,and then reduce the size back down (Not from scaling). Use point for images.